# How to get length of TypeScript Map<k, v>?(Error: Map.size gives undefined)

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, angular7

**I have Map in my angular component as key being object of class Group and value being an array of class Match which basically says group and matches that will take place among the group members of that group.
.**

Map< Group, Match[]>

I want to have the total number of entries in the map and length of match array as well. How do I do that?

I've tried map.size and map.values().next().length

Comment: If [`map.size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/size) didn't work, then it isn't a map. Please produce a [mcve].

Comment: But when I log the data then It works completely fine

Answer (score 7):

Sometimes `newMap.size` gives `undefined` value. Use this simple code to **find map size**.

```
Object.keys(newMap).length
```

Answer (score 3):

I encountered a similar problem. You have to call the Map constructor.
My original code was:

```
 let a : Map<string,number> = {} as Map<string,number>;
 Map.size //undefined
```

If you call it properly, then works:

```
let a: Map<string,number> = new Map<string,number>();
Map.size //the right size
```

Comment: `{}` is not a Map. That's a terrible type assertion what your are doing in the first example.

Comment: Indeed @Matthieu, that is why I am suggesting not to do it :) Found this in some old legacy code, and then figured that it is quite a bad approach.